# Why am I getting "error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'nlattr*'" when I use "nla_for_each_nested" on a nested array?

Tags: c++, netlink

I'm using `libnl3` and `nl80211.h` to get the available bands for a connected wireless interface.

When I try to compile I get `error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘nlattr*’`. The IDE (CLion) is also complaining about the line `nla_for_each_nested(nl_band, tb_msg[NL80211_ATTR_WIPHY_BANDS], rem_band)` and says `incompatible pointer type 'nlattr *' and 'void *'`.

What is being seen as `void *`, is it `pos = nla_data(nla)` from `/usr/include/libnl3/netlink/attr.h` that is considered `void *`?

Compile Error:

```
/home/username/Documents/Development/appname/fs_nl80211Class.cpp: In function ‘int callback(nl_msg*, void*)’:
/usr/include/libnl3/netlink/attr.h:328:21: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘nlattr*’ [-fpermissive]
  for (pos = nla_data(nla), rem = nla_len(nla);
                     ^
```

The macro from the `libnl3/netlink/attr.h` file:

```
#define nla_for_each_nested(pos, nla, rem) \
    for (pos = nla_data(nla), rem = nla_len(nla); \
         nla_ok(pos, rem); \
         pos = nla_next(pos, &(rem)))
```

My Code:

```
static int callback(struct nl_msg *msg, void *arg) {

    genlmsghdr *gnlh = (genlmsghdr *) nlmsg_data(nlmsg_hdr(msg));

    struct nlattr *tb_msg[NL80211_ATTR_MAX + 1];
    struct nlattr *tb_band[NL80211_BAND_ATTR_MAX + 1];

    struct nlattr *nl_band;

    int rem_band;
    static int last_band = -1;
    static bool band_had_freq = false;

    nla_parse(tb_msg, NL80211_ATTR_MAX, genlmsg_attrdata(gnlh, 0), genlmsg_attrlen(gnlh, 0), NULL);

    if (tb_msg[NL80211_ATTR_WIPHY_BANDS]) {

        // macro from libnl3/netlink/attr.h
        nla_for_each_nested(nl_band, tb_msg[NL80211_ATTR_WIPHY_BANDS], rem_band) {
            if (last_band != nl_band->nla_type) {
                cout << ("Band %d:", nl_band->nla_type) << endl;
                band_had_freq = false;
            }
            last_band = nl_band->nla_type;

            nla_parse(tb_band,
                      NL80211_BAND_ATTR_MAX,
                      nla_data(nl_band),
                      nla_len(nl_band), NULL);

            if (tb_band[NL80211_BAND_ATTR_FREQS]) {
                if (!band_had_freq) {
                    cout << "Frequencies:" << endl;
                    band_had_freq = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //nl_msg_dump(msg, stdout);

    return NL_SKIP;
}
```

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_ What the error message actually says.

Comment: You cannot use a `void*` when the argument type is `nlattr*`. You need to explicitly cast the `void*` to `nlattr*` before calling the function. Use `reinterpret_cast<nlattr*>(arg)` to do the explicit cast.

Comment: Why haven't you posted the code that contains the line with the error?

Comment: @Barmar are you referring to `/usr/include/libnl3/netlink/attr.h`?

Comment: I suppose so. Is `nla_for_each_nested` a macro defined in that file?

Comment: @Barmar, yes it is. I've added it.

Comment: What is the return type of `nla_data()`? The error implies that it returns `void*`, and you're trying to assign that to `nl_band`, which is `nlattr*`.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the header file was intended for use with C, not C++. C allows `void*` to be converted automatically to any other pointer type, but C++ doesn't.

Comment: I was wondering if it had to do with c vs c++. I'm using `iw` source as a guide and I do believe it's written in c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was g++ is unable to compile code with nla_for_each_nested macro due to implicit type conversion from void* to nlattr*.

See link from libnl list:

http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/libnl/2016-February/002096.html

The fix in the nla_for_each_nested macro was to add type casting for nla_for_each_nested macro.

Changed from:

```
for (pos = nla_data(nla), rem = nla_len(nla); \
```

To:

```
for (pos = (struct nlattr *) nla_data(nla), rem = nla_len(nla); \
```